# Como chamar método de uma window pai quando outra window filha for fechada com WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Olá, estou começando a trabalhar com WPF e minha situação é a seguinte:

- Tenho uma tela MainWindow, que persiste a aplicação.
- A MainWindow chama uma nova tela RegraDetailsDialog em determinada função.
- Assim que é executado um processo que fecha a tela RegraDetailsDialog preciso atualizar a MainWindow.

Na MainWindow, o método que chama a RegraDetailsDialog está abaixo:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void AddRegra(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegraDetailsDialog rdd = new RegraDetailsDialog();
        rdd.Show();
    }
    private void AtualizaTela(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("teste");
    }
}
```

Como faço para que, assim que a RegraDetailsDialog for fechada eu possa chamar o método `AtualizaTela` na MainWindow?

Comment: Você precisa chamar um método de outro formulário...Correto ? Observe a minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se chamar o método [ShowDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) que [abre uma janela e retorna somente quando a janela recém-aberta é fechada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx), e claro chamar logo após o método, exemplo:

```
private void AddRegra(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RegraDetailsDialog rdd = new RegraDetailsDialog();
    rdd.ShowDialog(); 
    AtualizaTela();
}
private void AtualizaTela()
{
    MessageBox.Show("teste");
}
```

só vai ser executado o `AtualizaTela` quando o `rdd` for fechado.

<sub>Referencia:</sub>

- [Método Window.ShowDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [WPF Dialogs and DialogResult](https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/wpf-dialogs-and-dialogresult/)

Comment: Então só preciso trocar o `.Show()` por `.ShowDialog()`?

Comment: @LeandroLuk sim... eu faria isso, por ser mais lógico, quando eu abacar de utilizar a tela filha atualizo a tela pai.

Comment: Realmente resolve meu problema... sinceramente não pensei que seria uma coisa tão simples... muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

No seu XAML da janela RegraDetailsDialog  você pode colocar

```xaml
<Window...Closing="Window_Closing" Closed="Window_Closed">

</Window>
```

Na classe coloque o código abaixo para chamar metodos da classe MainWindow.

```
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).AtualizaTela();
}
```